# I get an error when connecting to a SQL Server using Office 365 Excel - I have the driver installed

Tags: microsoft-excel, drivers, sql-server

I am using Office 365 Excel version 16.26

I am successfully connecting to the SQL Server database using Tableau 19.2

I have installed the SQL Server driver using the following commands:

[SQL Server driver install commands used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T5Us.png)

And I get the following error:
[SqlServerODBC] (15) Failed to connect to the SQL Server instance: [HY000]: Connection broken unexpectedly

Why am I getting this error - that's the question...

Comment: I am running on a MAC with Mojave  version10.14.5 installed.

Comment: Please check if the port is correct in the connection string.